# Build JavaScript associative array and pass to PHP using each loop

Tags: javascript, php, json, serialization, each

been trying to to create an object in javascript using input values and id's It works but when i try to serialize / stringify the object becomes empty.

My code:

```
        dataArray = [];

    $('.popover :input').each(function() {

        dataArray[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();

    });

    console.log(dataArray); 

    /*
    RESULT:
    Array[0]
        home_recent_jobs:"123"
        home_recent_jobs2:"345"
        length:0
        undefined:""
        __proto__:Array[0]
    */

    var json    = $(dataArray).serialize();
    var ser     = JSON.stringify(dataArray);

    console.log(json);      // RESULT: EMPTY
    console.log(ser);       // RESULT: []
```

Ideas?
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I make this code $("input[name='test_modal[]']:checked").each(function ()
{  checked[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();}var ser     = JSON.stringify(checked); console.log(ser);  and I have [null,"jordan","michael"]

    
    console.log(ser);

Comment: You may use dataArray.push($(this).val());

Comment: Thanks @dimis283 thats what i end up doind ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... after searching i found this solution - better each loop

new each loop:

```
    $('.popover :input').each(function (index) {

        var cid = $(this).attr('id');
        var cval = $(this).val();

        if(cid && cval) {
            var obj = { 
                id: cid,
                val: cval
            };
            dataArray.push(obj);
        }
    });
```

This seems to do the trick.
Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem some time ago.
Try to use this lib, it help me a lot

https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object

Comment: returns empty object. Guess i am building the object in a wrong way or something similar